# Version discrepencies with Imagemagick. How to fix?

Tags: imagemagick

It appears my install of the latest imagemagick is successful, but there is a discrepency when I query the version. identify -version shows the older version, and running it as `identify` calls the older version. Running `convert` does however call the more recent imagemagick.

There seems to be a default path issue, and I'm curious how to fix this without breaking something else :D

```
leo@thegrid:/usr$ /usr/local/bin/identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.4-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-12-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): gvc jpeg x xml zlib
```

But getting the version gives this:

```
leo@thegrid:/usr$ identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-11-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

But still, running "convert" does seem to bring up the proper version:

```
leo@thegrid:/usr$ convert

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.4-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-12-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP
```

What gives?

Comment: What does `which convert` return as the path?  You might need to create links to the versions you want.  The `convert` you might be looking for could be in `/usr/bin/` but the one you are running could be in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: `which convert` returns the proper path but I was under the impression `identify` was connected and important too. I might be wrong -- but what would be the most non-destructive way to redirect this?

Comment: You might want to look at `/usr/bin/convert --version` and `/usr/local/bin/convert --version`.  The default path is the one that will be called.  It sounds like you have two different versions installed and they are in different folders.

Comment: That is correct. Is there a way to make one or the other default?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` (which is where you should place additional local binaries) has a higher priority than `/usr/bin` (which is where the system's package manager installs software) by default. You can see that when you run `echo "$PATH"`, the leftmost path has the highest priority. I recommend not to change that though.

Comment: Might be best to backup the file from the one folder by renaming it to like `convert.bak`, then creating a link to the other file by `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/convert /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll noodle it based on what you've stated.